# Html dom parser problem in Domain

Tags: php

I have using simple html dom parser in php(simple_html_dom.php) for parsing the web page data and displaying it.
It works fine in localhost [wamp server] (http://localhost/test/read.php)but,
read.php:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.co.in/index.html');
    echo $html;
?>
```

I have website from yahoo small business domain(ex: www.mysite.com)

I was placed these two php files into my domain path like this,
http://www.mysite.com/test/read.php
and 
http://www.mysite.com/test/simple_html_dom.php

When i run the read.php from my domain, it stopped while reading this line,include('simple_html_dom.php');

Please anyone help me

Thanks,
Nandha

Comment: What is NOT working? What is the error message? What is `simple_html_dom.php`? Are you sure you have the file/library in your server

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that **allow_url_fopen** is enabled, **file_get_html()** makes use of `file_get_contents()`  which requires `allow_url_fopen` when used with HTTP